# High loopback count in Azure App Service TCP statistics, how to investigate?

Tags: azure, asp.net-core-webapi, azure-web-app-service, asp.net-core-2.1, azure-app-service-envrmnt

On our Azure App Service, running a .NET Core 2.1 Web API with SQL & REDIS dependencies, we sometimes get TCP port-exhaustion by a high loopback count.

Recent example:
[image: High TCP loopback count]

Here you see a high (2000+) connection count, and it is slowly decreasing. But very slowly. I think this would be a chance to try to find out what type of requests are staying open for so long.

When I run a network trace using the Azure Diagnostic tools, the loopback traffic is not logged, or at least I can't see them in the Message Analyzer.

Does anyone have an idea how to debug this loopback count?

**EDIT**
Last night I did an Deployment-slot swap (from staging to production). Same behaviour occured, see the following print-screen:
[image]

From 81 TCP connections it went to 418. Then it took about 12 hours for the TCP count to drop to "normal" as you can see.

Comment: If you haven’t tried this already, it could be due to Port limit on the App Service plan, you may consider Scaling-out and/or Scaling-up based on your requirement: Checkout this blog 
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2016/11/02/port-limit-for-an-azure-app-service/ for details.

Comment: Thank you. I'm familiar with the port limits of the various service plans. The normal behaviour is about 200 TCP connections for our application. And incidentally something happens and the TCP loopback connection explode to thousands and then slowly decrease. So there must be something wrong in my app what is causing this. But with 2k requests a minute on production it's hard to find the root cause. That's why I'm trying to investigate the process that's causing these loopbacks.

Comment: @AjayKumar-MSFT see added print-screen of a new situation that occurred. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: Interesting.  We have the exact same tech stack and are experiencing the exact same thing...

Comment: @Etch I also raised an Github issue: https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/13866

Comment: @JonHendrix, did you manage to figure something out?

Comment: @eddyP23 sadly no root cause. Few tricks we did: added decent application warmup so when swapping or scaling out, the first requests won't take much time. Second, we started migrating to .NET Core 3.1 with integrated mode, so no loopbacks are needed.